# I'm trying to get this elements margin-top and change it simply

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to get .SideArrow's margin top using js (since it's responsive and using calc()), and add a small pixel value to it with the menu, but only if .SideArrow has "display: inline-block". It is normally "display: inline", but changes with a media query.

I've got the "If it's display: inline" part down I think (haven't applied it to the function yet). The problem is getting the margin-top

I've tried what you can see in the code, and simply adding

```
var margin = document.getElementsByClassName("SideArrow").style.marginTop;
```

The problem I'm getting is it always responding with:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at (index):80

index:80 being
var style = window.getComputedStyle(arrows);

code:

```
var objName = "SideArrow";

//Function to toggle menu
var nav = document.getElementById("MobileNav");
var menubtn = document.getElementById("MobileMenu");
```

- 

```
var arrows = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("." + objName));
var margin = arrows.map(x => x.style.marginTop);

console.log(margin); //Both output []
console.log(arrows);
```

- 

```
alert(margin); //Doesn't alert anything

var mvalue = arrows.rules.marginTop;
var tvalue = 197;
var zvalue = mvalue + tvalue;

console.log(mvalue);
```

- 

```
function MenuToggle() {
  if (arrows.some(x => x.style.display == objProperty) && nav.style.height === "197px") {
    nav.style.height = "0px"; 
    menubtn.innerHTML = "menu"; //Using Material icons for now
    arrows.style.marginTop = "mvalue" + "px";

  }
  else if (arrows.some(x => x.style.display == objProperty) && nav.style.height === "0px") {
    nav.style.height = "197px";
    menubtn.innerHTML = "clear";
    arrows.style.marginTop = "zvalue" + "px";
  }
  else if (arrows.some(x => x.style.display != objProperty) && nav.style.height === "197px") {
    nav.style.height = "0px";
    menubtn.innerHTML = "clear";
    arrows.style.marginTop = "mvalue" + "px";
  }
  else {
    nav.style.height = "197px";
    menubtn.innerHTML = "clear";
    arrows.style.marginTop = "mvalue" + "px";
  }
```

- 

As shown in the code I want toe margin-top to add 197 pixels to it with the height of 'nav' when the function is ran (only when display is inline-block), but I can't even fetch the current margin-top correctly.

Update:
Updated the function itself, aka what's within the *.
And also the margin and arrow vars as @JackBashord showed me

EDIT:
I managed to work around it, and figured some other stuff out, so sorry to other people out there with the same problem.
I gave each arrow its own id and messed around with `margin-top` with `position: absolute`.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call `getElementsByClassName`, you're getting a NodeList, which is a type of array, rather than a single element. You can fix this by using `querySelector` instead:

```
var arrows = document.querySelector("." + objName);
```

And you can get the `margin-top` value without using `getComputedStyle` - just do this:

```
var margin = arrows.style.marginTop;
```

And then execute your function like so:

```
if (arrows.style.display == "inline") {
    MenuToggle();
}
```

Note: The above would only work if there was only one `.SideArrow` element. Here's how you'd do it for multiple elements:

---

```
var arrows = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("." + objName));
var margin = arrows.map(x => x.style.marginTop);
if (arrows.some(x => x.style.display == "inline") {
    MenuToggle();
}
```

Note: The above would make `margin` and `arrows` arrays.

Comment: Keep in mind that `document.querySelector` will only select the very first node.  To get any other nodes, you'll have to reference them using one of the selectors that returns a `NodeList` and reference it by index or some other identifying, specific trait.

Comment: But the OP did not specify whether he had a single item with that class name, or multiple elements. @SanderGodard, could you please specify?

Comment: That wasn't an argument, on my part, but an observation. Classes are typically assigned to multiple elements, so it's worthwhile to mention how this will work when applied to multiple elements.

Comment: I didn't expect replied this quickly!
Yes there are two elements with that class, so I'm going to try the second solution immediately. Lovely, thanks again!

Comment: Alright, so I've now tried it, and still don't get it to work.
`console.log(margin);
console.log(arrows);`
Both just output `[]`
And the log also complains this:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

On line 88 being `nav.style.height = "197px";`
The first line after the only `else` statement in the function.

Updated the main question to show the new function

Comment: Also feel like I should tag you @JackBashford
You've been very helpful, I appreciate it.